# Using gsub instead of strsplit or scan

Tags: r, split

Are there other possibilities to split a string instead of?

```
unlist(strsplit("1.2.3", "[.]"))
scan(text="1.2.3", what="", sep=".")
```

Comment: Why? What’s the problem with the solutions you’ve given?

Comment: the scan line does not work for me.

Comment: @KarlForner what's the error? It works for me. Klaus - is this just curiosity or do you have a use-case for which the perfectly reasonably suggestions you have given don't actually work? Is speed an issue? Do you have a super,super,superlong string?

Comment: now you edited it it works of course...

Comment: Is `str_split` from `stringr` too obvious?

Comment: Downvoted for unclear reason for the question.  Will remove downvote if you clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of R's pattern matching functions from the base package (see `?gsub`), `gregexpr` is the right one to use here. It will identify the start and end positions of chunks of characters that are not `.`, then you can reconstruct them using `regmatches`:

```
x <- "1.2.3.4as.zz2.zzxd3"

regmatches(x, gregexpr("[^.]+", x))[[1]]
# [1] "1"     "2"     "3"     "4as"   "zz2"   "zzxd3"
```

But really, I don't see what you gain over using `strsplit`. If you could tell us what it is you do not like about it, maybe we could be of more help.

Comment: Please answer flodel's last comment.

Answer (score -1):

gsub and sub. Sub is lazy so will only work on first occurrence (from left to right) of pattern. Gsub (global sub) will work on all of them.

```
> sub("asdkd_kasd_ads", pattern = "_", replacement = "")
[1] "asdkdkasd_ads"
> sub("asdkd_kasd_ads", pattern = "_.*", replacement = "")
[1] "asdkd"
> gsub("asdkd_kasd_ads", pattern = "_", replacement = "")
[1] "asdkdkasdads"
> gsub("asdkd_kasd_ads", pattern = "_.*", replacement = "")
[1] "asdkd"
```

Or in your case:

```
> gsub("1.2.3", pattern = "\\.", replacement = " ")
[1] "1 2 3"
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.